# Overwritten values outside of for-loop after numpy.insert

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I'm seeing the correct value when I print inside the for-loop, but when I convert it to a dataframe outside of the for-loop one of the columns get overwritten.

I've tried append, moving the insert statement in and out of the nested loop, concatenating arrays and numpy.column_stack.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
row_data = []
for i in range(2017,2019):
    url='https://superstats.dk/program?aar={}%2F{}'.format(i,i+1)
    html_doc = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc.content, "lxml")
    table_div = soup.find(id="content")
    rows = table_div.find_all('tr')

    for row in rows:
        cols=row.find_all('td')
        cols=[x.text.strip() for x in cols]
        if len(cols) > 0:
          row_data.append(cols[0:6])
          aar = soup.select_one('option[selected]')['value']
          aar_start, aar_slut = aar.split("/")
          aar_start_np = np.asarray(aar_start)
          row_data_np = np.asarray(row_data)

          new_row_final = np.insert(row_data, 0, int(aar_slut), axis=1)

    print(new_row_final)

df = pd.DataFrame(new_row_final, columns=['AarStart','Dag', 'Dato', 'Hold', 'Resultat', 'Tilskuere', 'Dommer' ])
print(df)
```

The result from print(new_row_final) show the correct results in the column "AarStart", where the first iteration of the loop is equal to 2018 and the second is equal to 2019. But print(df) just show 2019 throughout.

Comment: You don't accumulate or save `new_row_final` from one iteration to the next.  `row_data` is a list; you keep append to that (that's good).  But why make arrays and use `np.insert`?  I suspect it would better to stick with list operations, at least within the loop.  You can make arrays later.

Comment: To be honest, I got stuck with np.insert, because it showed me the correct the result for each iteration.